# Minecraft Client Server Login Protocol - Malformed public key bytes

Tags: java, networking, minecraft

I was able to get the server list ping to work fine but when I moved on to the login protocol, I'm having some issues.

After some analysis with Wireshark it looks like its sending the handshake and login packets in the same packet. I'm starting off with a offline login. Fom what I understand from the [Wiki](https://wiki.vg/Protocol#Login_Start), if you set `hasSigData` to false you don't need to send a public key and all that stuff. All I'm sending over is the username, `hasSigData` as false, and `hasPlayerUUID` as true with a UUID v3 derived from the string `OfflinePlayer:[username]`.

I have two questions:

1. Am I even encoding the login packet right. Yes the server I'm trying to log in to is in offline mode.
2. How do I separate the packets?

### Packet Hex dump from wireshark

[image]

I have marked out where the data starts and roughly where the handshake packet ends and the login packet begins.

### Server response

```
/[My IP] lost connection: Internal Exception: io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: Malformed public key bytes
```

### My code

#### LoginStart Packet (Offlne)

```
public static byte[] getLoginStartPacket(String name) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream loginStart = new DataOutputStream(buffer);

    UUID uuid = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(name.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    loginStart.writeByte(PACKET_ID);
    loginStart.writeChars(name);
    loginStart.writeBoolean(false);
    loginStart.writeBoolean(true);
    MinecraftUUID.writeBytes(loginStart, uuid);

    return buffer.toByteArray();
}
```

#### Sending Packet

```
    byte[] handshakeMessage = Handshake.getHandshakePacket(
                this.port,
                this.serverAddress,
                this.protocolVersion,
                2);

    VarInt.write(dataOutputStream, handshakeMessage.length);
    dataOutputStream.write(handshakeMessage);

    byte[] login = LoginOfflineStart.getLoginStartPacket(name);
    VarInt.write(dataOutputStream, login.length);
    dataOutputStream.write(login);
```

Comment: Minecraft packets are completely separate from TCP packets as TCP doesn't care what you call a packet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i figured it out when you send the username you need to add a byte before it to indicate the length of the username this as probably in the wiki sorry about that